# How to write C++ code that works between IDE?

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, cross-platform

I am new to **C++** from a C#.NET and Visual Studio background (and some Objective-C / XCode).

I want to write cross-platform (Windows, OS X, Linux) application with C++. I started with TextMate on my Mac and Notepad on my Windows, and compile the code using g++ on command line/terminal to build the executables on its platform.

I got confused when I started using IDE (namely **VC++**, **XCode**, and **Eclipse**). I tried all three and created projects before pasting my code in it. If I start editing in one IDE, I do not know how to get the eventual piece of code to compile on different platform.

For example, if I have a class file - `foo.cpp`. In Eclipse, it would generate `foo.cpp` (within it a `foo.h`, `foo::foo()`) and a separate `foo.h` header file (within it a `FOO_H_` file etc). In Xcode, it generates a folder `Foo` constains `main.cpp` and `foo.l`) - that's it. Why the difference?

I though C++ code is just C++ code which produce platform specific executables if compiled on that platform. (e.g. compile on Mac, it becomes a Mac executables; if compiled on Windows, it becomes a Windows executables).

It seems, once I started using IDE, my C++ code automatically become unportable, due to all these auto generated files that I have no understanding about. I try reading documentation on XCode, Eclipse, and Visual Studio at the same time, and it confuses me even further. I just want to write C++...

I am also following **Stroustrup's** classic text to pick up C++ and in the book, nothing like header or source of `.h` or `_H_` files were mentioned, as of why all these files were generated.

Besides using Notepad/Textmate + G++ compiler, how can I write pure, portable C++ program in an IDE that can be cross-platform, or is it even possible?

Comment: You need header files to share class definitions between compilation units, and library interfaces to other consumers. If you're doing everything in one file then you don't need them. The other project templates are likely just useful things for that platform, e.g. VC creates stdafx.h to use as a precompiled header to speed up including all the Windows API headers when you build etc. If you're worried, throw away the template project generated files and just start with an empty file.

Comment: And `FOO_H_` etc. is an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) - it's a mechanism to avoid re-parsing the header file twice if you include it twice in the same compilation unit through different routes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default (=most commonly used) file structure for a c++ class called `Foo` consists of a header file called `foo.h` which will contain the class definition of `Foo`, and a `foo.cpp` which contains the definition of the methods of `Foo`.

Often all the header files are put into a seperate folder called `include`.

So the general approach to have the same file/folder structure, which can be used for more than one IDE is:

- create the folder structure manually (e.g. `include`, `src` and `make` folders inside your project folder `MyProject`, the project files for IDEs would go into make, .h files into include, and .cpp files into src)
- create the .h and .cpp files for your classes manually using the explorer/finder/...
- use "add existing file" or something equivalent to add those files to the project file of your IDE.
- as Rup pointed out, for Visual Studio, one should use the "empty project" preset, or it will add some header files you dont want

Comment: +1. Just a remark: most IDEs (Eclipse, MSVC for example) allow to create .cpp and .h files (and to specify a folder for them),so it is not necessary to use explorer to create source files. Also Eclipse keeps project folders synchronized with filesystem structure by default, so directory creation  may be done using the IDE (just create a subfolder in your project)

Answer (score 1):

Use CMake or other meta-buildsystem
Use Boost and Qt to abstract away as much of the platform as possble.

CMake lets you generate project files for most IDE:s that mean when switching between platforms and IDE:s you just tell CMake to generate new project-files for that IDE you use on that platform.

Easiest to get platform-idependent code on windows, linux and mac is to use QtCreator as IDE, it also has a lot of good tutorials. http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: I, the OP, is already sadly confused, and now "CMake", "Use Boost" and "Qt"...huarrrrr

Comment: Boost and Qt are libraries that if you use them will hide much of details that are platform-specific. this means that will avoid having to write #ifdef _WIN32 .... in your code

Comment: sorry for flooding you with much new things, you are learning C++ and I should have taken notice of that. Updated answer with and link to an IDE that will let you write code in a platoform idependent way and the same IDE exist to all platoforms, so you will only have to learn ONE.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use 1 IDE for all? Eclipse is cross platform IDE

Comment: That's right, you only need to support multiple IDEs if you intend a wide range of people to compile your project themselves. If you intend to compile it yourself then you can just use multiple compilers in one IDE.